# Collaborative list or document in Slack

Tags: slack

My team is new to Slack. A common use case we are finding is "Let's make a list of X that we can all contribute to". Currently we share a Google Doc for every list/collaborative document, but this leads to an unmanageable set of random doc links floating around. Is the a way to do this in Slack in a more integrated way, so it keeps tracks of all our documents or lists? How do people solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried composing a "POST" that is editable by the group? Sounds like it solves the problem within Slack.

> **Compose a post**
>   Sometimes sharing detailed information with your team takes more than a message. Posts are a way to share and collaborate on long-form content — like project plans, or documentation — directly in Slack.
>   https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203950418-Composing-a-post

Answer (score 1):

I am using /todo for per-channel lists, as well as the custom slackbot responses to list url's for documents or other popular http based local network connections. Unfortunately it doesnt do file:// (yet)

An example of the slackbot command/response (edit to correct conflict with markdown. There should be three "backticks" - the other character on the tilde key - to denote preformatted text. This is what tricks the slackbot response into emitting multiple lines and not one of the lines in the response)

keyword      response
"doclist"    ```here is the doclist ``` ```some docs - [http://someplace/somefolder`](http://someplace/somefolder%60)``